# why doesn't this jquery add text to the div?

Tags: jquery

```js
$("#btn-id").click(function() {
  $.getJSON('employee.json', function(response, status) {
    if (status == "error")
      $('#err-id').text('Error Message: Not found');
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

  <button id="btn-id">Get Employee Data</button>
  <br><br>
  <div id="err-id"></div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="employee.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

The jQuery should add 'Error message' to div with id '#err-id'. But it doesn't do that. Why

Answer (score 1):

there is not status parameter in response, so try this (credits to
@freedomn-m)

```
    $.getJSON('employe.json', function(json) {
      // your code here
  })
  .fail((j, status) => { 
      $('#err-id').text('Error Message: status - '+j.status+ ' ' +j.statusText);
  });
```

getJson is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

so you can use ajax instead , but add an error option

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
  error: your error code here

});
```

Comment: @mplungjan OP  has fixed the question according to your comment.

Comment: `$.getJSON(url, successCallback)` is, as you say the equivalent of `success:` so response will not be `undefined` as the successCallback won't be called.

Comment: You could also add `.fail(jqXHR, status)` as in `$.getJSON(url, success).fail((j, status) => { });`

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks. Why you don't post your answer, it would be usefull for everybody. What would be response then? null? I don't think

Comment: The callback would never be called

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you again. You are right. I was finally able to make some tests, and fixed my answer according to your comments. You shoul post your answer, as I adviseed you before. Thanks again

Comment: No need for another answer, your summary of *there is no status parameter in response* is the answer.  The rest is just extra